# throwing a class type as an exception

Tags: c++, exception

```
class error
{
    int x;
    int y; 
public:
    error() { }

    error(int a,int b)
    {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<x<<endl<<y;
    }
};

main()
{
    error e;
    try{
        cout<<"press any key to test exception\n";
        getch();
        throw error(99,22);
    }
    catch(error e)
    {
        cout<<"\nexception caught successfully\n";
        e.display();
    }
}
```

`throw error(99,22)`, how can this statement throw a class object to the catch block?
if we write "throw e;" then it is understood that an object will be thrown but "throw error();" will call only constructor of that class,then how this code is working?

Comment: The same way you can do `std::string("abc") + "def"`. Also, `main()` must be `int main()`.

Comment: Also, standard C++ idiom is to catch by reference, not by value. That way you don't get object slicing, potential allocation errors, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a call to a constructor to give you a temporary object.

Let us say I have a class Frac to store rational numbers. It supports +, -, *, and / etc.

If I want to calculate (1/3 + 9/4) I could write that as:

```
Frac ans = Frac(1,3) + Frac(9,4);
```

The same goes for returning objects from functions:

```
Frac Frac::one() {
    return Frac(1, 1);
}
```

Or even throwing exceptions as is your use case:

```
throw std::logic_error("This is a call to logic_error's constructor");
```

Another tip while I'm at it, you should always catch exceptions in C++ "by-reference" that is like this:

```
catch (error & e) { /*...*/ }
```

The reason for this is to get the correct polymorphic behavior in the case where you have subclasses reimplementing virtual functions in your exceptions classes.